# YA Fantasy novel, early 90s, about a boy who releases evil from a cave

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

What I remember is that there's a young boy (I think his name is Garm?) who can talk with his horse (and maybe other animals). He accidentally releases ultimate evil from a cave (it was sealed by magic). The boy discovers his mom (I think?) is a witch, that he can be a wizard, and he eventually defeats the evil.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be "Gom on Windy Mountain" and sequels? I don't remember details, but the name partially matches and the [Goodreads summary](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/947041.Gom_on_Windy_Mountain) includes: "And Gom can talk to animals and to the wind".

The [Google Books summary](https://books.google.com/books/about/Gom_on_Windy_Mountain.html?id=pyu5uf14S5UC) of the series includes mentioning learning to be a wizard:

> The strange runestone left him by his mother, Harga, leads fatherless
> young Gom into mountain caves where he discovers the truth about his
> mother's disappearance on the day he was born. In the first sequel,
> The Riddle and the Rune: From Tales of Gom in the Legends of Ulm
> (1987), Gom travels across Ulm in search of Harga, making both friends
> and enemies while he struggles to solve a mysterious riddle. In The
> Crystal Stair (1988) Gom prepares for his seven-year wizardry
> apprenticeship by undertaking a dangerous journey back to Pen'langoth
> to find a mentor. In The Starstone (1989), Gom finishes his
> apprenticeship with Folgen and is called to fight against the wicked
> Katak.

Not sure about an ultimate evil sealed in a cave, though.